# Scraping Google Patents with requests only returns style and scripts tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape Google Patents using the following code.

```
    url = 'https://patents.google.com/?q=usb'
    r = requests.get(url)
    html_doc = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
```

But when I try to inspect the document, using

```
    print(soup.prettify)
```

I cannot get anything other than this https://pastebin.com/Xu81LdfE .
I checked the requests status and it is returning 200. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use google api's instead?

Comment: It's almost as if Google were purposefully making their content hard to scrape...

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the CSV download link shown at the top of the search results? https://patents.google.com/xhr/query?url=q%3Dusb&exp=&download=true

Comment: The CSV download contains exactly the fields I need, but it seems to be limited in the number of results it displays.

Answer (score 1):

The results on that page come for a different url:
https://patents.google.com/xhr/query?url=q%3Dusb&exp=

So instead of using BeautifulSoup, you could do r.json(), and find what you want in the dictionary it creates.

Answer (score 0):

The data is not in the HTML, but loaded with JavaScript.

Therefore, beautifulsoup cannot scrape it.

Consider using the official APIs, as other usage likely violates the Google terms of service, and they will likely block you then.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!